# Bootstrap Style is not Loading in angular 15

Tags: angular

I am create a new project and install bootstrap and jquery and popper and import bootstrap in angular.json But it is not working

```
"styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
```

Please Give any suggestion..
[image]

Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Did you restart the development server after editing `angular.json`?

Comment: yes i am restart

Answer (score 0):

I am missing to add
`@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`

in styles.css after adding these it is working Fine Thank you.

[image]